# CodeIgniter core library extensions within subfolders

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am curious if it is possible to organize library extensions within subfolders of the libraries directory within codeigniter application.

For example lets say we want to extend the 'Form_validation' library. The default way to extend this core library would be to create a class with the same name prepending 'MY_', and saving it as follows:

```
/application/libraries/MY_Form_validation.php
```

Now let's say we want to keep all of our extended libraries we have created within a subfolder called 'extensions' like such:

```
/application/libraries/extensions/MY_Form_validation.php
```

When trying the above the extended library is ignored and the default Form_validation class is loaded. Once this happened my first thought was to modify the subclass_prefix within /application/config/config.php to include the 'extensions' directory, however this resulted in an error stating:

```
Non-existent class: Form_validation
```

Is it possible to organize your extended libraries in this fashion within codeigniter? Does anyone know how it is done?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't.  I think CodeIgniter is set to only look in the `libraries` folder, not subfolders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If It's have a sub-folder

```
$this->load->library('extensions/MY_Form_validation');
```

and after you can access like..

```
$this->MY_Form_validation->your_function_name();
```